# I have a query with upload real time data to load in div without refresh in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making a chat function, in which I have put the chat records with while loop but I want to get new records with out refresh the div at the real time.

But If no record is updated new so div doesn't refresh because of scroll force me to bottom.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
     $("#mydiv").load("refreshmessages.php");
    }, 1000);
   });
   </script>

Comment: And your question is...? Also please add whatever code you have to your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use this (I guess u have php installed, you use a PHP page):

```
 var ajaxurl = "updatepage.php(CORRECT URL HERE)";
    var data = {};
data["CurBox"] = document.getElementById(IDOFCHATBOX).innerHTML
    $.post(ajaxurl, data
    , function (response) {
        func(response);
    });
```

and make sure you run checks on that the current chatbox is not already the same as when it would be updated! :)
use the post method inside the refreshscript to get the current chatbox contents